# Zip data extract and push to an external FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-extract

I am needing to zip and push data extension extract files to an external ftp. I recently enabled the 'zip' extract type in the account, which allowed me to zip files stored on the marketing cloud FTP site.  However, I am hitting a roadblock when trying to push these files to an external site.

I am needing the ability to either perform the zip extract on files stored in the safehouse. So, they can then be transferred from the safehouse to the external ftp. Or I need the ability to transfer files from the enhanced FTP to an external FTP.

Is there a custom extract or business rule that would allow for either of these asks?

1. zip files stored in the safehouse
2. transfer file from an enhanced FTP folder to an external FTP

Comment: I have an update from support.  I will post as an answer below.  Although it only partly solves for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered there is a custom extract that support can enable.  It is named 'Custom DE Extract With Zip2'.  The extract type will perform a data extract on a data extension and zip the file that it places in the Safehouse.  You can then perform a file transfer on this file to move it to the enhanced FTP or an external FTP.

The downside is that each individual extract file is zipped separately.  It does not allow you to group multiple files into a single zip.

Comment: I am trying to use this function but getting an error when I try to run the extract. Is there a "trick" to the required file naming format extension or the way the process works? In the extract definition I've tried using .zip and .csv without success.

Comment: Are you able to do a regular Data Extension Extract?  Just wanted to confirm your referencing the data extension customerKey correctly

Comment: When I used it last, I was able to enter a file pattern just as I would on a standard data extension extract.  So, the file name should end in .txt or .csv and not .zip

Comment: Thanks for response. I opened a ticket with support and was told that there was a previous issue with the code for that function which had been resolved but the fix hadn't been implemented on some of the server stacks. They were able to get it quickly resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I communicated with SF Support and they say that 'Custom DE Extract With Zip2' is outdated. Instead, ask them to enable data type "Data Extension Extract with File Encoding and gzip".

[Exporting a file from a data extention automation in salesforce marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309992/exporting-a-file-from-a-data-extention-automation-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud)