# Exporting a file from a data extention automation in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

There is a database extension in salesforce marketing cloud that I need to export from the automation. I didn't create the DE and am unsure how to export it for use outside of salesforce marketing cloud. It is from a SQL query. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.