# Data Loss in File Convert Data Activity Extract

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, automation, data-extract

Has anyone experienced a loss of data from "File Convert" Data Extract Activity?

I am exporting a synchronized data extension:

Step 1: Data Extract Activity - Export DE

Step 2: Data Extract Activity - File Convert to UTF8

Step 3: File Transfer - move from safehouse

The original extract from Step 1 has all 250k+ records but in UTF16 format.

The extract after file conversion in step 2 only has ~175k records.

Am I missing something? This is supposed to be a tried-and-true automation built into Salesforce.

Just going to end up running the conversion on my end if there is no real rhyme or reason to this data loss.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I clearly stated my problem: There is data loss in file convert. Gotta love AI.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to accurately predict what is the reason for data loss since you need to attach screenshots of your configuration and file sample but here is what you can do for the start:

1. Make sure you are extracting the unique file name to the Safehouse and there is no more similar automation with DE Extract that will do the same and interfere.
2. You can try a different option to convert the file into UTF-8 format. Check the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309992/exporting-a-file-from-a-data-extention-automation-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud).
3. Contact Sf Support to try to investigate at what point and why you have data loss